# Is this the correct way to cast delegates between each other?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to give my custom delegate as an input to `Task.Run()` but because `Task.Run()` accepts only Action and `Func<>` as a formal parameter so I changed my custom delegate variable to a proper `Func<int>` variable so that I can give this `Func<int>` variable to my `Task.Run()` method. I used the conversion by

```
        Del mydel = new Del(Get10);
        Func<int> xx = new Func<int>(mydel);
        int p = await Task.Run(xx);
```

Is this how casting between delegates is done or are there any other common ways to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
class Program
{
    public delegate int Del();

    public static int Get10()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public async Task DoAsync()
    {
        Del mydel = new Del(Get10);
        Func<int> xx = new Func<int>(mydel);
        int p = await Task.Run(xx);  

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", p);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = new Program().DoAsync();
        t.Wait();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why not just `int p = await Task.Run(Get10)` ? Why the multiple delegates?

Comment: `Task.Run(() => xx())` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to learn casting between same signature delegates so that I created this example to teach myself how to do this. Normally as you said it could be the shortest way of course.

Comment: @jenson-button-event why even xx? It's just a wrapper over the wrapper that wraps the actual function

Comment: @Lyrk why would you need casting between delegates in the first place? Just pass the lambda. What are you trying to do? And if you really need a Func delegate, why go through `mydel`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in my project I have custom delegates but Task.Run only accepts Func<> and Action as parameter. I have to convert my custom delegate to Func<>. I dont want to generate a new Func<> delegate.

Comment: @Lyrk anyway, you aren't *casting* here. You are creating new delegate instances that call one another. You could have created just one eg, `var xx = new Func<int>(Get10);`. These steps waste memory because they create extra delegate objects that aren't needed. In a hot path, this will create a lot of garbage and force frequent garbage collections

Comment: @Lyrk pass your delegate as is then and call it `Task.Run(()=>myDel())`, although you don't even need it. And check your memory usage. When debugging, go to `Debug > Windows > Show Diagnostic Tools`. I suspect you won't like what you see in the memory graph

Comment: Task.Run() accepts Lambda expression like in your example? I didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: @Lyrk that's why custom delegates aren't used since .NET 3.5 and *all* BCL libraries use Action and Func, except some leftovers for compatibility purposes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your patience and time for answering my question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158487/discussion-between-lyrk-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's the casting between Delegates, you are just using a `Delegate` object as a reference to the `Func` delegate with matching signature and what is happening is Func delegate instead of calling a method is calling a delegate which internally calls a method, so an extra level indirection, no purpose as such achieved. It's like a pointer to pointer, when you can actually refer to main reference / pointer

Review the following code:

**Your version**

```
Del mydel = new Del(Get10);
Func<int> xx = new Func<int>(mydel);
```

**Following will also work**

```
Func<int> xx = new Func<int>(Get10);
```

or

```
Func<int> xx = Get10;
```

What you are asking for is (casting):

```
Func<int> xx = (Func<int>) mydel;
```

Which will not work, since there's no type compatibility between a `Func` delegate and other custom delegate defined

Comment: Also to verify what I have mentioned check the IL of the compiled code, you will know how in your code Func Invokes MyDelegate, which internally Invokes the Method, when in other case that I have provided Method directly gets Invoked